# Codeigniter Session not updating immediately after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have sheet which contains a datepicker jquery input, with the function of onSelect routing to an ajax caller to my controller to update the Session with the date I have selected (below)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url('sickcalllog/sessions');?>",
      data: { key: 'datecall', value: $("#datepicker").val() }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
   });
    location.reload(true);
  }
});
```

The controller looks like this:

```
public function sessions()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata($this->input->post('key'),$this->input->post('value'));
    parent::sess_update();
}
```

This works. However, when I select a date it reloads the page with the current datecall session value, not the newly selected one. This has the effect of always being one selection behind.

Am I missing something in the code? do I need to delay for a second to give the session a chance to update?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I have now updated the function to read as below, but it doesn't seem that the function is working at all.

The code is now:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
      onSelect: function() {
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url('sickcalllog/sessions');?>",
          data: { key: 'datecall', value: $("#datepicker").val() }
       }).done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload(true);
       });

      }
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `location.reload` be inside the `done` section?

Comment: You are not waiting for your asynchronous AJAX request to finish, but are reloading your page as soon as you have _send_ the rest. You should do that inside the done handler instead.